# RadioButton with Custom View Android

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I'm trying to implement a radiobuttons with custom views like the below screenshot.

[image: RadioGroup with custom View]

The count of the radio button will be dynamic. I tried to create a `Radiogroup` and added the `RadioButton` to the `RadioGroup` using `addView` programatically. But it is not possible to `setText` as like in the attached screenshot. So I plan to add a `LinearLayout` and when `OnClick` the `LinearLayout` I will enable the `RadioButton` attached to the `LinearLayout` and disable rest of them. Whether it is the correct way to do that or is there any other way to implement that.

I also searched a lot. But I can't able to find anything similar to this. So, Please anyone suggest me the correct way.

Comment: You can use a custom ListView.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanks for your suggestion. Below dhinakaran-thennarasu posted a answer. I followed and implemented that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with Custom Listview.

activity_list_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom list item: radio_button_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/radioButtonLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Code XYZ" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCond"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:text="Rs.100 off if you purchase more than.." />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textValid"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Valid until dd/mm/yyyy" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now use a custom adapter to add content from Activity:

```
public class RadioButtonActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        //     RadioGroup  radioGroup  = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        final List<ItemContents> saveItems = new ArrayList<>();

        String code = null, condition = null, valid = null;

        // save your values here to the ItemContent List. usign dummy values as of now
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            code = "CodeXYZ000" + i;
            condition = "Purchase More than Rs." + i + "00";
            valid = "Valid until Dec 30";
            saveItems.add(itemContents(i, code, condition, valid));
        }
        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_list_view, saveItems);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                adapter.setSelectedIndex(position);  // set selected position and notify the adapter
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private static ItemContents itemContents(int i, final String code, final String condition, final String valid) {

        ItemContents itemContent = new ItemContents();
        itemContent.setId(i);
        itemContent.setmCode(code);
        itemContent.setmCondition(condition);
        itemContent.setmValid(valid);
        return itemContent;

    }
}
```

And the Custom Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ItemContents> {
    int selectedIndex = -1;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int activity_radio_button, List<ItemContents> saveItems) {
        super(context, activity_radio_button, saveItems);
    }

    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        selectedIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.radio_button_item, null);
        }

        RadioButton rbSelect = (RadioButton) v
                .findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        if(selectedIndex == position){  // check the position to update correct radio button.
            rbSelect.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            rbSelect.setChecked(false);
        }

        ItemContents itemContents = getItem(position);

        if (itemContents != null) {
            TextView textCode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCode);
            TextView textCond = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textCond);
            TextView textValid = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textValid);


            textCode.setText(itemContents.getmCode());
            textCond.setText(itemContents.getmCondition());
            textValid.setText(itemContents.getmValid());
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

And your output(I worked this on tv so the big screen)

[[image: Output[1]]