# How to add text hint inside a radio button

Tags: android

[image]Is it possible to add a text hint inside a radio button, as opposed to adding regular text next to it? Using the hint setting on the gui builder does not work.

Comment: Hint? It is something meant for `EditText`. Why normal text doesn't work for you?

Comment: i want to put 11 radio buttons in a row, when i put the text normally, they dont fit, if i can get text inside, they will. I tried resizing, but then text is too small

Comment: For me it looks like Two text views in linear vertical linear layout with radio button without text. It's just 3 widgets instead of one.

Comment: This is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33226886/11162243

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution i found working..

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<24) {
                    radio_button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color='"+ Color.BLACK+"'>"+getString(R.string.title)+ "</font></b>" +  "<br />" +
                            "<small> <font color='"+Color.GRAY+"'>" + getString(R.string.description)+"</font></small>" + "<br />"
                    ));
                }else
                {
                    radio_button.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><font color='"+ Color.BLACK+"'>"+getString(R.string.title)+ "</font></b>" +  "<br />" +
                            "<small> <font color='"+Color.GRAY+"'>" + getString(R.string.description)+"</font></small>" + "<br />"
                    ),Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
                }
```

Comment: and instead of the if condition, you may use:
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(htmlCode,HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)